# Getting input values from user that is not related to account database

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to get the inputField to accept values that are NOT in any Salesforce database [i.e object]?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<apex:inputField />` tag must be bound to a field on an sObject.

All of the other `input` tags can be used as you see fit.